# Convert datetime to int seconds microseconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of strings like `'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913'`.
How can I convert this series to obtain juste the int number after "." : `2913`.
Thank all !!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: In fact i did an error in a previous code that takes a lot of time to run that's why i'm trying to correct just the values of this column of my dataset . 

I had at the beginning a column with int and i convert it to datatime : 

df_concat_OPF_copy['fup_thoracic']=pd.to_datetime(df_concat_OPF_copy['fup_thoracic']) 

I obtain a column : 

1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913 
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002914

And now i want to reverse this command and retrieve the values 2913, ...

Comment: Btw, what is after the dot is only microseconds/nanoseconds, the seconds are the last two digits after the last colon. You should clarify if you need them ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.nanosecond`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.nanoseconds.html)/[`microseconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.microseconds.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
s.dt.microsecond*1000+s.dt.nanosecond
```

output:

```
0    2913
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Op expcted 2913 but you got 913. Perhaps you meant microsecond?

Comment: Thank you for your return, but I want 2913.

Comment: @CeliusStingher you're right, I updated the answer

Comment: I wouldn't use pandas for such a simple task. That sounds like way too much overhead.

Comment: @Rightleg the question has a pandas tag, I assume the data is a Series or a DataFrame. Also OP specified "*I have a **series** of strings*"

Comment: Ah, my bad. you're right.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pandas series made of strings like the one you show. I believe the most efficient solution would be to use a list comprehension and assign it to a new series, for example:

```
df['Microsecond'] = [x.split('.')[1] for x in list_of_values]
```

However if you want a more pandas-ian approach, then you can try using:

```
df['Microsecond'] = df['date'].str.split('.').str[0].astype(int)
```

Why does the list comprehension approach work? Because for a single value what you are requesting can be done used `int` and `.split('.').

```
int('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913'.split('.')[1])
```

Returns:

```
2913
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a string, then just parse it:

```
s = "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002913"
value = int(s.rsplit(".", 1)[1])
```

`str.rsplit` splits the string starting from the right, and it takes a number of times to split as parameter, so `rsplit(".", 1)` does the least required work.

Then you just convert that to an `int`.